# Do we need a transit visa we have a 12 hour stop over and have booked a hotel, we are flying with AirIndia from Sydney to Rome return

Tags: visas, india, australian-citizens, transit-visas, new-zealand-citizens

I am traveling with my elderly parents, sister and her son. He is 19 years old. We are traveling to Rome, from Sydney return on Air India. We have a 12 hour stopover in Delhi, so I have booked a hotel without thinking about the transit visa. I have a New Zealand passport, my parents have both New Zealand and Australian Passports and I'm not sure what my sister's or nephew's passports are.

I would like to know if we need transit visas and how to get them before we depart Australia.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like as New Zealand or Australia passport holders you can get a transit or visitor visa. Links provided by @pnuts in the comments are helpful.

The transit visa seems way cheaper than the regular visitor visa, [at 28 USD,](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/indiavisa/transit-visa-india.html) but there is a priori no procedure explained online.

The visitor visa costs 60 USD which is expensive compared with a hotel room price. According to the [electronic visa website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_India), you should apply for it online and then obtain it on arrival. Note that your passport must be valid for 6 months after you leave India. You should apply between 4 and 30 days before entering India (actually the payment should be made at least 4 days in advance so i would do it early enough for the payment to be processed at least 4 days in advance) The procedure is [explained there](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html).